# How to set doctrine associated data into Zend Form?

Tags: doctrine-orm, zend-framework2

How To set associated data into zend form in ZF2?

I am getting this error :

> Zend\Form\View\Helper\FormSelect does not allow specifying multiple selected values when the element does not have a multiple attribute
>   set to a boolean true

after using the below code.

```
$data =  Entity Object[
    'name' => 'test'
    'email' => 'test@test.com',
    'type' => Object[
      'id'=>1,
       'type'=>'admin'
       ]
    ]
```

when I used for set data

```
$form->setData($data->toArray())
```

it gives me above error.

I am using ZF2, Doctrine2 , MysQL

Please help me to fix this.

Comment: Could you paste your form definition ?